# Store list of Objects into FlowPane

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a custom object which I would like to store into FlowPane. For example I tried to create list of custom objects and to inset them into FlowPane but I failed:

```
private final List<LivePerformanceChart> list = new ArrayList<>();
private final FlowPane flow = new FlowPane();
flow.getChildren().addAll(list);
```

I'm looking for a way to store custom chart objects into FlowPane and to update chart values using one Sheduled Task. The simple way that I can think of is to iterate all FlowPane children and to update the chart values using public Java methods.

Can you show me some example how I can do this?

EDIT:
I also tried this:

This is my custom class:

```
public class LivePerformanceChart{......}
```

LivePerformanceChart zz = new LivePerformanceChart();
flow.getChildren().add(zz);

Here I get:
no suitable method found for add(LivePerformanceChart)

```
method Collection.add(Node) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; LivePerformanceChart cannot be converted to Node)
method List.add(Node) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; LivePerformanceChart cannot be converted to Node)
```

I can try to iterate over the children this way:

```
for(int i=0; i<flow.getChildren().size(); i++){

                        Node obj = flow.getChildren().get(i);

                        if(obj instanceof LivePerformanceChart){


                        } 

                    }
```

Here I get

```
incompatible types: Node cannot be converted to LivePerformanceChart
```

Can you help me to solve the problem?

Comment: again: it's your job to come up with some code that demonstrates the problem ...

Comment: Children added to a FlowPane must be a Node.  Your LivePerformanceChart is not a Node - so you can't add it a FlowPane.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the similar technique to add my objects of Label into the List of flowpane. Here is the sample code which i am using -

```
Flowpane fpmoduleContainer[app] = new FlowPane();
 ArrayList<Label> listlbs = new ArrayList<Label>(moduleList.size());
                    int i = 0;
                    for (ModuleAttribute mattribute : moduleList) {
                        listlbs.add(new Label());
                        listlbs.get(i).setText(mattribute.getModule_name());
                        i = i + 1;
                    }
                    fpmoduleContainer[app].getChildren().addAll(listlbs);
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Could you please show me some example with FlowPane and Custom Object. I don't understand some of the code that you pasted.

Comment: It turns out that this code is not useful for me because you store list of objects which are Node. In my case I get `no suitable method found for addAll(ArrayList<Custom_Object>)`